# Hibernate Bidirectional one-to-many with composite key

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-annotations

I am trying to create a bidirectional one-to-many association between two entities where the many side has a compound key. And one of the keys of the many side is coming from the one side. Also, I need to have the many side the owner of the association. Below is an example code showing what my code looks like.

**Without Jointable**

Parent Class which is the one side. I need to have this side owner of the association.

```
    public class parent{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns({
                  @JoinColumn(name="NAME", nullable = false),
                  @JoinColumn(name="PARENT", nullable = false)})
    private Set<Child> childs;
}
```

Child Class which is the many side. Its primary key is "name" and "parent". "parent" is coming from the association.

```
public class child{

    @EmbeddedId
    @AttributeOverrides({
            @AttributeOverride(name="parent", column=@Column(name="PARENT", nullable=false)),
            @AttributeOverride(name="name", column=@Column(name="NAME", nullable=false))})
    private ChildId id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns({
                   @JoinColumn(name="PARENT", nullable = false, updatable = false, insertable = false),
                   @JoinColumn(name="NAME", nullable = false, updatable = false, insertable = false)})
    private Parent parent;
}
```

ChildId is the Embedded id.

```
@Embeddable
public class childId{

    @Column(name = "PARENT")
    private String parent;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;
}
```

**With Jointable**

Parent Class

```
    public class parent{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name="PARENTCHILD",
                joinColumns= {@JoinColumn(name="PNAME", referencedColumnName = "NAME", nullable = false)},
                inverseJoinColumns = {
                        @JoinColumn(name="CNAME", referencedColumnName = "NAME", nullable = false),
                        @JoinColumn(name="CPNAME", referencedColumnName = "PARENT", nullable = false)})
    private Set<Child> childs;
}
```

Child Class

```
public class child{

    @EmbeddedId
    @AttributeOverrides({
            @AttributeOverride(name="parent", column=@Column(name="PARENT", nullable=false)),
            @AttributeOverride(name="name", column=@Column(name="NAME", nullable=false))})
    private ChildId id;

    @MapsId("parent")
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name="PARENTCHILD",
                inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="PNAME", referencedColumnName = "NAME", nullable = false)},
                joinColumns = {
                        @JoinColumn(name="CNAME", referencedColumnName = "NAME", nullable = false),
                        @JoinColumn(name="CPNAME", referencedColumnName = "PARENT", nullable = false)})
    private Parent parent;
}
```

**Question1**:
This code doesn't work. In case of "without jointable", it gives the below exception.

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: A Foreign key refering com.entity.Parent from com.entity.Child has the wrong number of column. should be 1
```

**Question2**:
And in case of "with jointable", it gives below exception:

```
SQLCODE=-530, SQLSTATE=-23503, SQLERRMC=PARENTCHILD.FK_PARENTCHILD_CHILD
```

Comment: You dont need to have a composite key for this problem, as the parent name will be inserted as Foreign Key into Child by Hibernate itself.To make Parent as the owner of the relation please add mappedBy =  parent in the child @ManyToOne . That should solve all your problems.

Please verify and accept the answer I gave with code snippets below.

Comment: I gave you the code in the answer, you dont need to join, just try the code that I gave.See my answer below, try that code and let me know what problem you face.

Comment: Thanks @BirajChoudhury. I know this much that parent will be in child table as a foreign key. But, assume that uniqueness of child is identified with parent's name. Then, assuming primary key of child as EmbeddedId, your code will be same as mine.

Comment: I didnt understand your comment, do you agree with my solution or not ? Or I havent understood your problem ? I am asking this bcoz I know how to make that error go - "A Foreign key refering com.entity.Parent from com.entity.Child has the wrong number of column. should be  1 " , I am just not sure you need it.

Comment: @BirajChoudhury. I think you have not understood my problem. Simple, I have a Child class which is unified with the combination of a "name"(String) attribute and a "parent"(String) attribute which is the primary key of the Parent class. Please accept this assumption that uniqueness of Child is defined with these two. Then, a child object could have one parent and a parent object could have many childs. You can find an example of EmbeddedId [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#collections-bidirectional) in 5.1.2.1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to keep Parent name as Id separately in Child , Hibernate will do that for you . I have made a simpler design .And you can control the relation by using mappedBy = childs ,in the `@ManyToOne` or `mappedBy = parent` in the `@ManyToOne` side.

```
@Entity
    public class Parent{

    @Id
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Child> childs;

    public Parent(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Parent(){}
}

@Entity
public class Child{

    @Id
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private Parent parent;
}
```

Three tables will be generated by Hibernate

Child Table with columns name(Primary Key), parent_name(Foreign Key) 
Parent Table with one column name(Primary Key)
Parent_child table with two columns parent_name and child_name

EDIT : Solution changed as per amir's needs, just add mappedBy whichever side you need to control the relationship.

```
@Entity
public class Child implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private String name;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private Parent parent;
}

@Entity
public class Parent{

    @Id
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Child> childs;

    public Parent(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Parent(){}
}
```

EDIT - To name column in child side

```
@Id()
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="xyz")
private Parent parent;
```

Comment: Man, still the primary key of the Child class you are giving is ONLY **Name** attribute. Primary key of Child is composed of two attributes:
1- name
2- parent (this one is also the primary key of Parent Class under the name of "name")
Just look at my code

Comment: Execute it and see , I am able to see 3 tables, Table child now has 2 primary keys, and parent_child table now has 3 columns, parent, child and  child_parent . I am executing code for you, and you are complaining without executing this is not fair.

Comment: Sorry man and thanks for your solution. Your code works, But, it doesn't give me any flexibility in terms of choosing the name of Columns. Could you please tell me how I can change the name of jointable and its columns name. Also, how can I pick an arbitrary column name for the parent's name in the Child table.
If EmbeddedId should not be used here, what is the purpose of it then?

Comment: for instance, name of jointable and its columns

Comment: I added code so that you can name column of the child's parent name, also for the child's name you can just do @column(name = "xyz")  and table name you can do above public class Child with @Table(name = "xyz") . I hope all your queries are met now.

Comment: Could you please show how the jointable columns could be renamed?

Comment: Do we have a join table in this code ? Where did join table come from, by join table if you mean the child's parent name , and how you could change its name , I have shown that in the code above .

Comment: Your code generates 3 tables Child, Parent, and Parent_Child. This Parent_Child table is jointable. I want to be able to change the name of the Parent_Child table and its columns' names.

Comment: Parent_child table is being generated from the Parent OneToMany relationship, you can add some @joincolumn there to change the names of the columns

Comment: it give me `this class [class name of class] does not define an IdClass`.

Answer (score 0):

To use One-To-Many bidirectional mapping using join table,use following code:

> Parent Class

```
 public class parent{
        @Id
        @Column(name = "id")
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)    
        private Long id;
        .....
        .....
        @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinTable(name="Parent_Child", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name ="parentId", referencedColumnName ="id")},
            inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name ="childId", referencedColumnName ="id")})
        private Set<Child> children;
        .....
        .....
 }
```

> Child Class

```
 public class Child{
        @Id
        @Column(name = "id")
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)    
        private Long id;
        .....
        .....
        @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinTable(name="Parent_Child", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name ="childId", referencedColumnName ="id")},
            inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name ="parentId", referencedColumnName ="id")})
        private Parent parent;
        .....
        .....
 }
```

Note that I have used `OneTOMany` mapping in `Parent` class - cause as per your logic a parent can have multiple children and I have used `OneToOne` mapping in `Child` class cause one child will have one parent(as mentioned in your requirements).

Hope this helps

Comment: You shouldnt use CascadeType.ALL in both side of the relationship, as if you delete a Child , it will try to delete its parent , but it cannot delete the parent because all other childs of that parent are still active, so Hibernate will throw error. Also deleting the parent will kill all the child. Please understand this is a relation of association and not composition.

Comment: Also most of the annotations you added aren't necessary , the Table Id is already self explanatory as it is name. You need to add @Column(name = "xyz") to add meaning and increase readability  but here you are changing a perfectly readable table to obscure naming. This doesnt add any value but decreases value. Also no @JoinTable is necessary. When Hibernate is doing all work for you why are you bloating the code.